# javascript save multidimensional array for php

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

This is my data in php:

```
$userLimit = array(
    "default" => array(
         "playlistLimit" => 1,
         "mediaLimit" => 2,
            ), 
     "editor" => array(
          "playlistLimit" => 5,
          "mediaLimit" => 20,
            ), 
     "author" => array(
           "playlistLimit" => 2,
           "mediaLimit" => 10,
            ), 
      );
```

When I loop this in php I get:

```
foreach ($userLimit as $k => $v) {
        var_dump($k);
    }

string(7) "default" string(6) "editor" string(6) "author"
```

This is correct, its what I want.

When I edit it in javascript (and send to server side ) I do this:

```
var userLimit  = [
{
    "default": {
        "playlistLimit": "1",
        "mediaLimit": "2"
    }
},
{
    "editor": {
        "playlistLimit": "5",
        "mediaLimit": "20"
    }
},
{
    "author": {
        "playlistLimit": "2",
        "mediaLimit": "10"
    }
}
]
```

then I need to serialize it when sending server side:

```
JSON.stringify(userLimit)
```

the problem is when this comes back and I loop it again in php I get as keys:

```
 foreach ($userLimit as $k => $v) {
        var_dump($k);
    }

int(0) int(1) int(2)
```

because the data now looks as this:

```
array(3) { [0]=> array(1) { ["default"]=> array(2) { ["playlistLimit"]=> string(1) "1" ["mediaLimit"]=> string(1) "2" } } [1]=> array(1) { ["editor"]=> array(2) { ["playlistLimit"]=> string(1) "5" ["mediaLimit"]=> string(2) "20" } } [2]=> array(1) { ["author"]=> array(2) { ["playlistLimit"]=> string(1) "2" ["mediaLimit"]=> string(2) "10" } } }
```

How can I make the data not change format after its saved?

Comment: Either change your JS structure to be an object (do you really need it to be an array?) or just parse index 0 in PHP when the data comes in

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The JavaScript equivalent of an associative array is an object, not an array of objects.

```
var userLimit = {
  "default": {
    "playlistLimit": "1",
    "mediaLimit": "2"
  },
  "editor": {
    "playlistLimit": "5",
    "mediaLimit": "20"
  },
  "author": {
    "playlistLimit": "2",
    "mediaLimit": "10"
  }
}
```